# A strange symbol

Tags: symbols

In the Lathi-Ding's book on communication systems, there is a strange wavy overbar as it is shown in the attached figure ... how can i use it in LaTEX?[image]

Comment: This suggests the creation of a package `olem` (cf. `ulem`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `\lfilet` growing delimiter of `mathabx`, sized to the width of the material and rotated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{ <-> s*[0.6]mathx10 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lfilet}{4}{mathx}{"37}{mathx}{"37}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\overfilet}[1]{{%
  \mathpalette\over@filet{#1}%
}}
\newcommand{\over@filet}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#2\vphantom{^1}$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th
    #1\left\lfilet\vbox to 0.55\wd\z@{}\right.
    \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  $}%
  \vbox{\ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\box\tw@}\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip}
    \box\z@\cr
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
P_g = \overfilet{g^2(t)} + \overfilet{g(t)g(t\pm\tau)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `s*[0.4]mathx10` instead of `0.6`, the output would be

[image]

Comment: Amazing. The `0.4` option looks better to me.